The timeline function on iOS 18 is not carried out according to the set array of entries
The timeline function on iOS 18 is not carried out according to the set array of entries. For example, I set two entries, the first entry shows the current view1, and the second entry takes 2 seconds to display view2. But the actual effect on iOS 18 is view1 and view2 at the same time and it shows up right away. This problem doesn't exist on iOS 17.
func timeline(for configuration: EmergencyAlarmWidgetIntent, in context: Context) async -> Timeline<Entry> {
      var entries: [Entry] = []
      let currentDate = Date()
      let alarmModel = alarmModel(for: configuration)
            
      let entry = Entry(date: currentDate, alarmModel: alarmModel,type: .loading)
      entries.append(entry)
            
      let entry1 = Entry(date: currentDate.adding(.second, value: 2), alarmModel: alarmModel,type: .bindDevice)            
      entries.append(entry1)
      return Timeline(entries:entries, policy: .atEnd)
}


Clicking Button or Toggle triggers the timeline function to refresh. Triggers the above problem.
